# Retrieve hyperlink value from <li> in HTML body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regular-language

I need to get the href value in HTML body tag by regular expression

```
<html>
    <head>
  </head>
  <body class="directory">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="/">~</a> / <a href="/public">public</a> / <a href="/public/img">img</a> / <a href="/public/img/events">events</a> / <a href="/public/img/events/poster">poster</a> / </h1>
      <ul id="files" class="view-tiles"><li><a href="/public/img/events" class="" title=".."><span class="name">..</span><span class="size"></span><span class="date"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-1.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-1.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-1.PNG</span><span class="size">1406471</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:23</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-2.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-2.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-2.PNG</span><span class="size">530859</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:44</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-3.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-3.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-3.PNG</span><span class="size">551409</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:38:24</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/test" class="" title="test"><span class="name">test</span><span class="size">0</span><span class="date">2018-10-4 20:16:58</span></a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

I want to have a list that contains

```
/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-1.PNG and 
/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-2.PNG and
/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-3.PNG.
```

The expression i used :

```
/[<body\sclass="directory">].+[<li><a\shref\s*=\s*\"]([^">]+)\"\s+[class].+[<\/body>]/g
```

However i got the result:

```
<ul id="files" class="view-tiles"><li><a href="/public/img/events" class="" title=".."><span class="name">..</span><span class="size"></span><span class="date"></span></a></li>

<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-1.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-1.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-1.PNG</span><span class="size">1406471</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:23</span></a></li>

<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-2.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-2.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-2.PNG</span><span class="size">530859</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:44</span></a></li>

<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-3.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-3.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-3.PNG</span><span class="size">551409</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:38:24</span></a></li>

<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/test" class="" title="test"><span class="name">test</span><span class="size">0</span><span class="date">2018-10-4 20:16:58</span></a></li></ul>
```

Can someone guide me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

`/<li[^>]*>[^<]*<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"/g`

and then access the `href="([^"]+)` capturing group by calling `match[1]` like follows (assuming you are using javascript):

```js
    var myString = `<html>
    <head>
  </head>
  <body class="directory">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="/">~</a> / <a href="/public">public</a> / <a href="/public/img">img</a> / <a href="/public/img/events">events</a> / <a href="/public/img/events/poster">poster</a> / </h1>
      <ul id="files" class="view-tiles"><li><a href="/public/img/events" class="" title=".."><span class="name">..</span><span class="size"></span><span class="date"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-1.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-1.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-1.PNG</span><span class="size">1406471</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:23</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-2.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-2.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-2.PNG</span><span class="size">530859</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:44</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-3.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-3.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-3.PNG</span><span class="size">551409</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:38:24</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/test" class="" title="test"><span class="name">test</span><span class="size">0</span><span class="date">2018-10-4 20:16:58</span></a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>`;

var myRegexp = /<li[^>]*>[^<]*<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
  // matched text: match[0]
  // match start: match.index
  // capturing group n: match[n]
  console.log(match[1])
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) for the code example.

---

#### Update 1

*Author asked to include a match for the body tag*

> Just curious. How do i update the express if i want to limit mapping range in  tag? I update the express as belows but no result. ]*>.*]*>[^<]*]*href="([^"]+)".*</body[^>]*>

There is only so much you can do with a regex and in general it's not recommended doing advanced html parsing with regexes. Your approach gives you problems with the linebreaks and the fact that you want to match multiple `li`s in a single body.
Also, by HTML convention, `<li>`s are only allowed in the body.

If you want to do so, break it down into two steps and match the

```js
    var myString = `<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Not valid HTML, just for testing -->
    <ul id="files" class="view-tiles"><li><a href="/public/img/events" class="" title=".."><span class="name">..</span><span class="size"></span><span class="date"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-1.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-1.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-1.PNG</span><span class="size">1406471</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:23</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-2.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-2.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-2.PNG</span><span class="size">530859</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:44</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-3.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-3.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-3.PNG</span><span class="size">551409</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:38:24</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/test" class="" title="test"><span class="name">test</span><span class="size">0</span><span class="date">2018-10-4 20:16:58</span></a></li></ul>
  </head>
  <body class="directory">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="/">~</a> / <a href="/public">public</a> / <a href="/public/img">img</a> / <a href="/public/img/events">events</a> / <a href="/public/img/events/poster">poster</a> / </h1>
      <ul id="files" class="view-tiles"><li><a href="/public/img/events" class="" title=".."><span class="name">..</span><span class="size"></span><span class="date"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-1.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-1.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-1.PNG</span><span class="size">1406471</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:23</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-2.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-2.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-2.PNG</span><span class="size">530859</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:37:44</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/2018-09-26-3.PNG" class="" title="2018-09-26-3.PNG"><span class="name">2018-09-26-3.PNG</span><span class="size">551409</span><span class="date">2018-9-16 18:38:24</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/public/img/events/poster/test" class="" title="test"><span class="name">test</span><span class="size">0</span><span class="date">2018-10-4 20:16:58</span></a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>`;

var bodyRegex = /<\s*body.*>([\s\S]*)<\s*\/body>/g;
var bodyString = bodyRegex.exec(myString)[0];

var myRegexp = /<li[^>]*>[^<]*<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(bodyString);
while (match != null) {
  // matched text: match[0]
  // match start: match.index
  // capturing group n: match[n]
  console.log(match[1])
  match = myRegexp.exec(bodyString);
}
```

Comment: @TzuHaoChung glad I could help. Please remember to mark the answer that solved your problem best as *accepted* once you don't require any further input.

Comment: Just curious. How do i update the express if i want to limit mapping range in <body> tag? 
I update the express as belows but no result.
    <body[^>]*>.*<li[^>]*>[^<]*<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)".*<\/body[^>]*>

Comment: @TzuHaoChung see my updated answer. It becomes unpractical and at some point impossible to match nested html tag relations. Break it down into several steps like shown or consider using a html parser library to do more complicated queries.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a regular expression? This solution seems to work.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#files a');
  links.forEach(link => {
    console.log(link.getAttribute('href'));
  })
```

Comment: It is a html file from somewhere. The js code is not in the same page.